# No relevant work experience in current job. What to do?

Tags: job-search, complaint

This is my first post on WorkPlace SE. It might be long but I need your help.

I am from India and graduated in Electrical and Electronics Engineering from one of the top 10 Engineering Institutes in the country. Unfortunately, the courses taught greatly deviated from what the degree was and focus more on Communication Engineering than Electrical Engineering.

I got internship as an Intern Data Science Associate in an MNC from the Oil and Gas sector. I had only basic knowledge of coding and no more of coding knowledge, but since the internship was compulsory, I accepted the internship. Unfortunately, all the superiors, that is the manager, senior data scientists and team lead, none had worked as a Data Scientist ever in their previous roles and had very little knowledge about the work that was being done by the lowest level employees, the "Data Scientists", who were all freshers, none from Computer Science background, but who were more knowledgeable than the superiors. I was given only text extraction and little image processing projects which used Tesseract OCR and OpenCV Python, but no core ML/AI work as such, over my internship duration as such, whereas the "Data Scientists" were working on core AI/ML projects using Tensorflow and Keras to build their own models. At the end of internship, I was given the opportunity to work as a Full Time Employee Data Scientist in the company and I accepted the offer as my father had retired and I would be the only earning person in my family.

The real problem started now. As soon as I joined full-time, I was handed a VB.NET project (while I did not know anything about VB.NET) which had been going on the past 1.5 years, which my supervisor could not himself complete (despite claiming himself as an expert in VB.NET). The VB.NET project was not related to my designation at all and furthermore, it used a third party API which was (and still remains) broken (this was accepted by the API developing company's service employee). I worked on this project for a month and realized this and communicated this to supervisor as well as my manager. But the project was not moving ahead and the manager insisted on finding a breakthrough. After another one month of failed attempts, I asked my manager if he could give me another project so that it things could move on and I gain some learning in my first job. But he refused stating that the VB.NET project was on top priority and I had to work on it only. I approached my manager's manager and explained to him the situation, and he told me that millions of dollars had already been invested in a complementary project and without the VB.NET project coming to completion, the millions of dollars would go to waste.

I started applying for jobs on LinkedIn and other websites, but no company has yet called me for interviews. It has been a year now since I have been in this job (full-time) and the project is still stuck. I am getting very nervous. Please help me to know how I can tackle this situation.

Answer (score 3):

The project is important to your company and they have asked you to work on it.

Therefore, you should try to complete the project to the best of your ability. If you might not complete the project then you need to communicate this with your management team and ask for advice....

.... it sounds like you have already done this and they have instructed you to try and work on it anyway.

Keep working. Keep communicating. Job done.

> He told me that millions of dollars had already been invested in a
> complementary project and without the VB.NET project coming to
> completion, the millions of dollars would go to waste.

This is a problem for your manager.

Or whoever it was that made a disastrous investment decision and has pinned their hopes on it being fixed by a single junior developer.

Comment: It is not possible to complete the project as the third party API that is used is broken, and the third party is reluctant to repair it.

Comment: @CommonMan  - You say "reluctant" - that means that with pressure they may be persuaded to fix it. This is not a job for you (and maybe not even for your direct manager) - someone high up needs to put the necessary pressure on them (maybe even threaten to sue, depending on the conditions of the sale of the API).  Tell  your manager that you are working hard but you cannot change someone else's API. There are two ways ahead  ...

Comment: ... (1) they fix their API or (2) you develop an equivalent API. Option 2 will of course take much more time.  Strongly express your desire to get the work done to a high standard; *hint* at the possible solutions (you can't tell your manager what to do), and then leave it up to the management to decide the way forward.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you need to determine what field you'd like to work in and the jobs you'd like to target.

Second, prepare for the target field. If it is anything remotely coding and software related (like machine learning or data science), you can build projects and showcase them on a GitHub profile.

One thing is that the current pandemic situation means that fewer companies are hiring. Use this lull to work on and showcasing a portfolio.